# How to induce to different functions on JIRA transition state

Tags: jenkins, workflow, jira, devops, jira-plugin

My Problem statement is that in JIRA workflow I have to fire a webhook invoking Jenkins pipeline if while moving a story from review to done state. But again the condition is that it should fire this pipeline only if the story is Dev. If story is related to research/POC/AnyOther it should not invoke the webhook.

[As in the image it shows that story will move from review to done with transition state name "DONE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnEI4.png).

Now in the same transition state post functions I want trigger the post function which in turn invoke Jenkins pipeline iff the story is dev in nature.
How can I achieve this using any free-plugin?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to install [JIRA Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin)
2. Config jira block in main settings
3. Read [jira jql doc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html)
4. Look at examples from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md)
5. Example for your story:

   ```
   def jiraProjectKey = "PROJECT_KEY"
   def version = "dev"
   def jqlQuery = "project = ${jiraProjectKey} and fixVersion = '${version}' and status = 'Review'"
   def workflowAction = "Move to Done"

   step([$class: "JiraIssueUpdateBuilder",
      jqlSearch: "${jqlQuery}",
      workflowActionName: "${workflowAction}",
      comment: "${comment}"])
   ```